# How to crosstabulate two variables to classify a third categorical variable in R

Tags: r, crosstab

I want to crosstabulate `x` by `y` to obtain in the table cells, the values of `z`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
             y = c("c", "d", "c", "d"),
             z = c("e", "g", "f", "h"))

# I want to obtain this result:
#   c   d
# a e   g
# b f   h
Created on 2021-07-18 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `tidyr::pivot_wider`...

```
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = y, values_from = z)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  x     c     d    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     e     g    
2 b     f     h
```